# Leaflet карта с рисованием полигонов

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование, leafletjs

Может кто знает как подключить Leaflet карту с возможностью рисовать полигоны на карте и потом отправлять координаты на почту (второстепенно). У меня не получается. Надеюсь на вашу помощь!
[image: карта]

Comment: Уточните что именно не получается, желательно с кодом, логами и т.д.

Comment: Как установить карту leaflet и сделать так, чтобы на нём можно было рисовать полигоны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для установки карты на вашу страницу необходимо:

1) Добавить Leaflet CSS(в `<head>`):

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
```

и скрипты(перед `</body>`):

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
```

2) Добавить контейнер для карты на страницу:

```
<div id="mapid"></div>
```

3) Задать желаемую высоту контейнера(иначе будет 0):

```
#mapid { height: 180px; }
```

4) Добавить на карту слои и необходимые объекты, например:

```
const mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

const polygon = L.polygon([
    [51.509, -0.08],
    [51.503, -0.06],
    [51.51, -0.047]
]).addTo(mymap);

L.tileLayer('https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Рабочий пример:
https://codepen.io/styfrombrest/pen/rNNGKya

Comment: Спасибо. А можно сделать так, чтобы отображалось именно то место, где находится (приблизительно) пользователь и данные координат отправлялись на почту после верификации формы?

Comment: Можно. Вот тут API для работы с геолокацией: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation Проверяете разрешение на доступ к геоданным, запрашиваете доступ если необходимо, получается текущие координаты и устанавливаете на карте через setView(). Верификация, формы и отправка - это уже отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @Khisrav если ответ вам был полезен - не забудьте отметить его